# How do I parse serialized JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing, serialization

I am trying to use a third party client API to get some information in my application.

The URL is http://www.claritin.com/weatherpollenservice/weatherpollenservice.svc/getforecast/94542. It gives a strange kind of output when I try to get the response via OpenURI:

```
require 'opne-uri'
require 'json'
url = 'http://www.claritin.com/weatherpollenservice/weatherpollenservice.svc/getforecast/94542'
JSON.parse(open(url).read)



JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '"{\"pollenForecast\":{\"zip\":\"94542\",\"city\":\"HAYWARD\",\"state\":\"CA\",\"forecast\":[6.4,6.6,8.1,7.6],\"pp\":\" Olive and Privet.\",\"timestamp\":\"May 24, 2014 11:16:13 PM\"},\"weatherForecast\":{\"date\":\"May 27, 2014 8:06:33 AM\",\"city\":\"Hayward\",\"state\":\"CA\",\"zip\":\"94542\",\"forecast\":[{\"lowF\":56,\"highF\":68,\"iconDay\":\"3200\",\"iconNight\":\"3100\",\"skyDay\":32,\"skyNight\":31,\"phraseDay\":\"Sunny\",\"phraseNight\":\"Clear\",\"date\":\"May 24, 2014 12:00:00 AM\"},{\"lowF\":55,\"highF\":78,\"iconDay\":\"3200\",\"iconNight\":\"3100\",\"skyDay\":32,\"skyNight\":31,\"phraseDay\":\"Sunny\",\"phraseNight\":\"Clear\",\"date\":\"May 25, 2014 12:00:00 AM\"},{\"lowF\":54,\"highF\":77,\"iconDay\":\"3200\",\"iconNight\":\"3300\",\"skyDay\":32,\"skyNight\":33,\"phraseDay\":\"Sunny\",\"phraseNight\":\"Mostly Clear\",\"date\":\"May 26, 2014 12:00:00 AM\"},{\"lowF\":51,\"highF\":71,\"iconDay\":\"3000\",\"iconNight\":\"3300\",\"skyDay\":30,\"skyNight\":33,\"phraseDay\":\"Partly Cloudy\",\"phras
```

How can i parse this into JSON or Ruby hash format.

Comment: Sadly, they're sending around their JSON as evaluatable JavaScript instead of **actual** JSON.

Comment: You could try to correct json string before parsing, like: `JSON.parse(open(url).read.gsub(/\\"/,'"')[1..-2])`

Comment: @meagar thanks. It helped as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186399/evaluate-javascript-on-ruby

Comment: @meagar It's just a JSON object serialized into a string, likely a mistake.

Comment: `'opne-uri'` should be `'open-uri'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tamer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23889509/1120015) is close, but its output will be an unescaped text:

```
text = open(url).read
# => "\"{\\\"pollenForecast\\\":{\\\"zip\\\":\\\"94542\\\",\\\"city\\\": ... \""

ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(text)
# => "{\"pollenForecast\":{\"zip\":\"94542\",\"city\":\"HAYWARD\",\"state\": ...}"

ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(text).class
# => String
```

To actually receive the JSON text as a hash - you need to run decode *twice*

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(text))
# => {"pollenForecast" => {"zip" => "94542", "city" => "HAYWARD", "state" => ...}

ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(text)).class
# => Hash
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
json_data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(open(url).read)
```

[ActiveSupport::JSON.decode](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html#method-i-decode)

You might need to remove the beginning and ending double quotes only, so it becomes:

```
json_data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(open(url).read[1..-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here: "[Evaluate javascript on Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186399/evaluate-javascript-on-ruby)"

```
    require 'v8'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'json'

    url = 'http://www.claritin.com/weatherpollenservice/weatherpollenservice.svc/getforecast/94542'

    javascript = open(url).read


     cxt = V8::Context.new
     result = cxt.eval(javascript)


    JSON.parse(result)
```

Comment: In this case, using a javascript execution engine just to extract the JSON from the string is a bit overkill, IMHO.